# SQL Server "order by" and "rows" clause in window functions is not working in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

I am getting error as:

```
Incorrect syntax near 'ROWS'.
```

While executing below query in SQL server 2014:

```
select  SC_CODE, [Date] , High ,Low, 
                                Max(High) over (partition by SC_CODE 
                                order by [Date]         
                                ROWS BETWEEN 6 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as 7DayHigh,
                                High / Max(High) over (partition by SC_CODE) * 100 as Percentage_wrt_High,
                                Min(Low) over (partition by SC_CODE 
                                order by [Date]         
                                ROWS BETWEEN 6 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as 7DayLow,
                                Low / Min(Low) over (partition by SC_CODE) * 100 as Percentage_wrt_Low
from dbo.NSE
```

To the best of my understanding, Windows articles, and this forum posts, partition by is supported in sql server 2012+.

[image: screenshot of my Sql server 2014 Help --> About page]

Kindly suggest if any plugin or update required to be installed in order to properly use partition by clause. Or any workaround that may be used.

**Additional Findings:**
If I comment out the `rows between` part, then i am getting error as:

```
Incorrect syntax near 'order'.
```

And if I comment out the `order by` part also, the query gets executed without any error.

So in a nutshell the partition by clause is working fine, but the order by and rows sub-clause when added to the query, I get the error mentioned above.

This is a very basic query for now, but going forward, I intend to add a lot more columns for analysis purpose and determining details like, past 7 days high, past 1 month high, past 52 weeks high, 7 days moving average, 1 month moving average, etc

Any suggestions/workarounds that may be extended to my larger scope are also welcomed. Thanks.

Comment: Identifiers can not start with numbers (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874.aspx), they must be delimited by double quotation marks or brackets.

Comment: Your screenshot only shows the version of SQL Server **Management Studio** not the version of the _server_ you are using. What does `select @@version` give you?

Comment: It gives: Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.3042.00 (Intel X86) 
 Feb  9 2007 22:47:07 
 Copyright (c) 1988-2005 Microsoft Corporation
 Express Edition on Windows NT 6.1 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

Comment: Strange, i have downloaded and installed from microsoft website few days back.

Answer (score 1):

```
select 1 as 8jh--this fails

select 1 as j8h--this works

select 1 as [8jh]--this works
```

If ask is regarding how to get rid of error..using brackets [7DayHigh] helped me parse the query..so query will  get past syntax errors..

```
select  SC_CODE, [Date] , High ,Low, 
    Max(High) over (partition by SC_CODE      order by [Date]   ROWS BETWEEN 6 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as [7DayHigh],
    High / Max(High) over (partition by SC_CODE) * 100 as Percentage_wrt_High,
    Min(Low) over (partition by SC_CODE   order by [Date]   ROWS BETWEEN 6 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as [7DayLow],
    Low / Min(Low) over (partition by SC_CODE) * 100 as Percentage_wrt_Low
from dbo.NSE
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response, but even after using brackets [7DayHigh], same error. Also, as i mentioned in question, when i comment order by and rows clause, the query is getting executed, so column name starting with number doesnt look to be the actual problem in my case.

Comment: Well actually, just observed that while commenting the order by and rows clause i had removed the column name also along with the comment, so it mitigated this error and i was able to execute the query. So column name starting with number was also an error in my query, but unfortunately not the main error that i am looking for.